# flutter: error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Encrypted' of 'encrypted'

Tags: encryption, flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm using : [encrypt: ^3.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)
I'm using AES encryption in flutter but when i decrypt my encrypted value it's give me this type of Error.

flutter: error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Encrypted' of 'encrypted'

```
Future<String> getEncryption(String text) async {
    String enc = '';

    final SharedPreferences strFamilyPass =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    strFamilyPass.getString('family');

    final String keys = await getKEY();
    final dynamic key = Key.fromUtf8(keys);
    final dynamic iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final dynamic encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final String salt = await getSalt();
    enc = '$salt${encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv).base64}';
    print('encryption $enc');
    return enc;
  }

  Future<String> getDecryption(String text) async {
    String dec = '';
    final String keys = await getKEY();
    final dynamic key = Key.fromUtf8(keys);
    final dynamic iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final String salt = await getSalt();

    dec = '$salt${encrypter.decrypt(text, iv: iv)}';// it give's me error right here
    print('decy $dec');
    return dec;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) said It all:

```dart
String decrypt(Encrypted encrypted, {IV iv})
```

You passed a `String` to `Encrypted`, and [Encrypted](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/blob/1f8250010056af50352a557b191f7c9fd931f5fb/lib/src/encrypted.dart) is not a subtype of `String`.

Comment: Okay I'm passing Encrypted data and i got this
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid character (at character 29)
73R634pZF8gPztaH7Qn7eu1U41BA==
                           ^
)

Comment: Sorry, this is an another question, and I have never used that plugin. This seems to be you passed the wrong *Encrypted data*, but I can't talk more about this.

Comment: Okay Thanks Sir,

Comment: You could mark as sloved, so let readers know this issue is sloved :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var source = 'flutter app';
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(source, iv: iv);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, where I was converting the encrypted Data to string and needed it back for decryption:

```
    var source = 'flutter app';
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(source, iv: iv);
```

The above method worked just fine(Miriam's answer).

For normal Direct decryption, you can use the decrypt method directly, as:

```
        final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
    final iv = IV.fromLength(8);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(Salsa20(key));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
```